# Selecting a submatrix of a binary matrix NP hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, combinatorics, matrices

I have the following problem and I am wondering if it is NP Hard or not.

Let $A$ be a binary matrix whose rows and columns are indexed by the sets $\mathcal{I}=1,...,m$ and $\mathcal{J}=1,...,n$.
A rectangle is a set $R=I\times J$ with $I\subseteq\mathcal{I}$, $J\subseteq\mathcal{J}$ and its value is defined by
$$f(R) = \left|\left\{(i,j) : A_{i,j}=1,i\in I,j\in J\right\}\right|+\left|\left\{(i,j) : A_{i,j}=0,i\in \bar{I}\text{ or }j\in \bar{J}\right\}\right|.
$$
For a given binary matrix $A$, the problem consists in finding the rectangle with the highest value.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?  Can you share the source where you saw it or the motivation?

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to the following problem: given a matrix, all of whose entries are +1 or -1, find a rectangle that maximizes the sum of the entries in the rectangle.  (Proof: replace all 0's in your matrix by -1's.  This changes the value of the objective function by a constant that does not depend on  $I$ or $J$, namely, by the total number of 0's in your matrix.)

Comment: Which rectangle???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is NP-hard.  In particular, it is equivalent to maximum edge weight biclique problem (MWBP), which is known to be NP-hard.

## Maximum edge weight biclique

MWBP is the following problem: given a bipartite graph with weights on the edges, find a [biclique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) that maximizes the sum of weights on the edges in the biclique.  It has been shown to be NP-hard in papers in the research literature.  There are also inapproximability results.  See, e.g.,

- Milind Dawande, Pinar Keskinocak, Jayashankar M. Swaminathan, Sridhar Tayur.  [On Bipartite and Multipartite Clique Problems](http://public.kenan-flagler.unc.edu/faculty/swaminaj/research/paper/DKST.pdf), Journal of Algorithms, 2001, vol 41, pp. 388-403.
- Arti Pandey, Gopika Sharma, Nivedit Jain.  [Maximum Weighted Edge Biclique Problem on Bipartite Graphs](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-39219-2_10).  Conference on Algorithms and Discrete Applied Mathematics: CALDAM 2020.
- Jinsong Tan. [Inapproximability of Maximum Weighted Edge Biclique via Randomized Reduction and Its Applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0468v2), Theory and Applications of Models of Computation: TAMC 2008.

I also want to highlight the following thesis, which discusses techniques for approaching this problem:

- [Finding maximum sum submatrices](https://www.info.ucl.ac.be/%7Epschaus/assets/thesis/2021-derval.pdf), Guillame Derval, PhD dissertation, UC Louvain.

## Equivalence with your problem

If $R$ is a rectangle, let $n_1(R)$ denote the number of 1's within $R$, $n_0$ the number of 0's within $R$, $n_0(\overline{R})$ the number of 0's within $\overline{R}$ (i.e., the entries that are not within $R$), and $n_0(A)$ the number of 0's within the entire matrix.  Then $n_0(A) = n_0(R) + n_0(\overline{R})$, so $n_0(\overline{R}) = n_0(A) - n_0(R)$.  Also your objective function $f$ is defined as

$$f(R) = n_1(R) + n_0(\overline{R}).$$

Therefore

$$f(R) = n_1(R) - n_0(R) + n_0(A).$$

Of course, $n_0(A)$ does not depend on $R$, so maximizing $f(R)$ is equivalent to maximizing

$$g(R) = n_1(R) - n_0(R).$$

Now this in turn is equivalent to a MWBP problem: you replace all the 0 entries in $A$ with $-1$; then the goal is to find a rectangle $R$ where the sum of entries in $R$ is maximized; but treating that matrix as the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph, each rectangle $R$ corresponds to a biclique, and maximizing the sum of entries in $R$ is equivalent to maximizing the sum of edges in a biclique.

It follows that your problem is equivalent to the MWBP problem, and therefore is NP-hard.